# Shortest path visiting all nodes without going back to start

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Let's say that we have an arbitrary set of nodes and we want the shortest path between the nodes AND we have to visit all the nodes in the graph. It's sort of Travelling Salesman Problem but without going back to the start node again. Assume that we can start from any arbitrary node and end at any arbitrary node (except the starting node), but we have to visit all the nodes in the graph. Is the complexity the same as the Travelling Salesman Problem i.e NP-hard? Is there any known algorithm to solves this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for Stack Overflow. For guidelines on asking questions, please see the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Yes, this is still TSP, just a slight variation of it. Note that the reduction from Hamiltonian Path to this problem is fairly trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still TSP, and is NP-Hard. The algorithms that work on TSP will work on this one as well. Note that the fact that you "do not care" what is the starting node is insignificant, because by trying all possibilities, you multiply the complexity by `n`.

The reduction from [Hamiltonian Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) to this problem is fairly trivial:

Given a graph `G=(V,E)`, create a new weighted graph with `G'=(V,E',w)`, where:

```
E' = V x V (all edges are there)
w(u,v) = 1 if (u,v) is in E
w(u,v) = 2 else
```

Now, the original graph `G` has a Hamiltonian Path if and only if shortest path that goes through all vertices is of length `|V|`.